# Filter List in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

I have a problem here. I have an react api and i want to make a select box to filter data by specific attribute.

```
constructor() {

    super();
    this.state = {
        results: []
    };
}
```

I receive a list of items with name and ratings. And I want to filter with select. If I want to see just items with 5 rating or greater, select 5.

```
return (

<div className="container clearfix">
  {/* value={props.search}  */}
  <select>
    <option value="" />
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    {props.results

      .map(item=> (
        <div key={item.id} className="item-holder">
          <img src={`${imagePath}${item.image}`} />
          <span className="votes">{item.rating}</span>
          <p>{item.title}</p>
        </div>
      ))}
  </div>
</div>

);
```

TX!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to attach a listener to `Select` e.g.

```
<Select onChange={(event) => this.setState({filterValue: event.target.value})}
```

then you can filter the results with

```
props.results.filter((item) => item.rating >= this.state.filterValue)
             .map(...)
```